# Wrong https redirection with two websites on the same server

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, ssl, redirection, virtual-host

I have two websites, call them **example-1.com** and **example-2.com** deployed on the same server (**CentOS 7.5**) both served by apache at port 80. The redirection is performed with Virtual hosts (see below for the full configuration).

For both sites I redirect (permanently) the **non** http urls to https (no problem with the certificates, bot work fine).

> The problem I encounter is that the http version of the second website
>   redirects (moved permanently, 301) to the https of the first one (the order of the sites is according to the .conf files below).

This redirect does not happen with the second website redirecting to the first (see the confs below), also everything works as it should if there is no need to redirect from http to https, i.e. I start with https://www.example-2.com .

Here are the **.conf** files, any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example-1.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example-1.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example-1"
    ServerName www.example-1.com
    ServerAlias example-1.com

## logging
   ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/example-1-error_log"
   CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/example-1-access_log" combined

        <Directory "/var/www/html/example-1">
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-1.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-1.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-1.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/plain text/xml application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

and the **conf** of the second website (notice that the only difference, except names, is that in this second one we do not have the **Listen 80** at the top)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example-2.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example-2.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example-2"
    ServerName www.example-2.com
    ServerAlias example-2.com

## logging
   ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/example-2-home-error_log"
   CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/example-2-home-access_log" combined

        <Directory "/var/www/html/example-2">
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-2.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-2.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-2.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/plain text/xml application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've finally located what was wrong in my configuration. I'm posting it here just in case anyone will have a similar problem.

I changed the server names to www equivalents and added server aliases without www, namely
the  directives now become

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example-1.com
    ServerAlias example-1.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example-1.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and the same adjustment for the second website. This settled the incorrect redirection problem for me.